# Как получить url активной вкладки chrome?

Tags: c#, url, google-chrome, tab

В общем обошел весь stackoverfow. Никак не могу найти рабочий коd

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте это:

```
// there are always multiple chrome processes, so we have to loop through all of them to find the
// process with a Window Handle and an automation element of name "Address and search bar"
Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (Process chrome in procsChrome) {
  // the chrome process must have a window
  if (chrome.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
    continue;
  }

  // find the automation element
  AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(chrome.MainWindowHandle);

  // manually walk through the tree, searching using TreeScope.Descendants is too slow (even if it's more reliable)
  AutomationElement elmUrlBar = null;
  try {
    // walking path found using inspect.exe (Windows SDK) for Chrome 31.0.1650.63 m (currently the latest stable)
    var elm1 = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Google Chrome"));
    if (elm1 == null) { continue; } // not the right chrome.exe
    // here, you can optionally check if Incognito is enabled:
    //bool bIncognito = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetFirstChild(elm1)) != null;
    var elm2 = TreeWalker.RawViewWalker.GetLastChild(elm1); // I don't know a Condition for this for finding :(
    var elm3 = elm2.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, ""));
    var elm4 = elm3.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ToolBar));
    elmUrlBar = elm4.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Custom));
  } catch {
    // Chrome has probably changed something, and above walking needs to be modified. :(
    // put an assertion here or something to make sure you don't miss it
    continue;
  }

  // make sure it's valid
  if (elmUrlBar == null) {
    // it's not..
    continue;
  }

  // elmUrlBar is now the URL bar element. we have to make sure that it's out of keyboard focus if we want to get a valid URL
  if ((bool)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty)) {
    continue;
  }

  // there might not be a valid pattern to use, so we have to make sure we have one
  AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmUrlBar.GetSupportedPatterns();
  if (patterns.Length == 1) {
    string ret = "";
    try {
      ret = ((ValuePattern)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0])).Current.Value;
    } catch { }
    if (ret != "") {
      // must match a domain name (and possibly "https://" in front)
      if (Regex.IsMatch(ret, @"^(https:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}).*$")) {
        // prepend http:// to the url, because Chrome hides it if it's not SSL
        if (!ret.StartsWith("http")) {
          ret = "http://" + ret;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Open Chrome URL found: '" + ret + "'");
      }
    }
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Хех, UI Automation всегда поможет :) +1

Comment: Уже пробовал.  if ((bool)elmUrlBar.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty)) { возвращает null